# Naming classes on a framework that present multiple platforms

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, naming, atomic-design

Our company has recently started developing a new UIKit. This framework is being developed using the atomic design methodology and is present on three different platforms: web, iOS, and Android.

In a recent meeting, the discussion revolved around whether the class and property names of simple or complex views to be developed should be the same. While I have my opinion on this matter, there are different views within the team. For instance, one argument suggests naming a TextView, one of the framework's atoms, as Label in iOS to align with Apple's naming conventions, claiming that it facilitates faster adaptation during development.

In my opinion, for a common language among developers, whether they are actively involved in development or not, consistency is crucial.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this matter and would greatly appreciate any references you might have.